# How to delete multiple items from DataGridView using a check box column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

here's the code for that loads `DataGridView`.

```
private void btnLoaddata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddCheckBoxforDataGridView();
    try
    {
        conDB.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = conDB;
        command.CommandText = "select CWDetails,CCSpn_CODE as 'SPN CODE',CCFname as 'First Name',CCLname as 'Last Name',CCMname as 'Middle Name',CCDOB as 'Date Of Birth',CCgender as 'Gender',CCSchool as 'School',CaClass as 'Class',CCVillage as 'Village',CCSiblings as 'Number Of Siblings',CCGuardian as 'Guardian',CCContact as 'Contact',CCcurrentDt as 'Date Of Entry' from abaanaCC";
        // command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@IMG", imageBt));
        // command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //MessageBox.Show("Record Saved");

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        EditdataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to Load Data");
    }
    conDB.Close();
}
```

here's Code that adds the `checkbox` column to the `DataGridView`

```
private void AddCheckBoxforDataGridView() 
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn() 
    {
        Name = "Check"
    };
    EditdataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
}
```

Here's the Method created to Delete. The `CWDetails` column is the `primary key` in the database

```
public int DeleteMult(int CWDet)
{
    conDB.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = conDB;
    string query = "delete from abaanaCC where CWDetails = " + CWDet + "";
    command.CommandText = query;
    int res =  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conDB.Close();
    return res;
}
```

Here's the code for the delete button `del_Mult` which is not working

```
private void del_Mult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < EditdataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        row = EditdataGridView1.Rows[1];
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[1].Value);
            DeleteMult(id);
            EditdataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
            i++;                     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try to do it in a foreach loop so you don't have to mess with `int i`, like this:

```
private void del_Mult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DataGridViewRow> deleteRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in EditdataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[1].Value);
            DeleteMult(id);
            deleteRows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in deleteRows)
    {
        EditdataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

Although you have to make a list of rows you want to delete, since you cannot delete rows while you are busy iterating over them.

Comment: thanks but how do i make the list since i am using a check box column to select rows to delete

Comment: @ElijahAyeeta It's allready in the answer: `List<DataGridViewRow> deleteRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();` makes the list for the rows to be deleted, and afterwards I'm iterating over that list to actually delete them `foreach(DataGridViewRow row in deleteRows)`. So this code snippet should be plug and play for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using ***i*** for retrieving grid rows. Also you don't need ***i++*** since you are doing that in for loop already.

```
row = EditdataGridView1.Rows[i];
```

Remove *i++* statement from *if* condition.

Comment: thanks i can now be able to delete, except one row, that is if i selected 3 rows, one of them refuses to delete